# JQGrid Empty Dropdownlist validation

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I create a jqgrid with dynamic dropdownlist. This is working well. My question is, if the dropdownlist is empty means the edit form show the error message please select the field while we edit or add the form details.

Answer (score 1):

Make a [custom function](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules) like

```
var fld1, fld2,
check = function (value,columnname) {
    if (columnname === "fld1") {
        fld1 = value;
    } else if (columnname === "fld2") {
        fld2 = value;
    }
    if (fld1 !== undefined && fld2 !== undefined) {
        // validate the fields here
        return [false, "please enter text"];
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};
```

In your jqgrid ,

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
colModel: [ 
    {name: 'fld1', editable: true, 
        editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: check}},
    ]
});
```

Comment: { name: 'FLD_TYPE_NAME', index: 'FLD_TYPE_NAME', width: 150, editable: true, edittype: "select", editrules: { required: true, custom: true, custom_func: function (value, colname) { alert('enter here'); //Not Working while add new record } }, editoptions: { value: "", style: "width:125px" }, formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 3, elmprefix: "&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='required'></span>&nbsp;"} },